# How does Reminders launch the app?

Tags: debugging, windows-phone-7, reminders

I am having a few problems getting my Windows Phone 7 app-specific `Reminder`s to work properly - the app re-closes after a fraction of a second after starting to show the splash-screen.

In order to debug this, I'd like to know how a `Reminder` launches an app, which events are fired and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what it might be worth - here is what I found out.

A Reminder restarts the app, triggering the Launching-event in App.xaml.cs. That is - you need to re-load anything you need to make the app work from Isolated Storage or the web

When the Launching event is done with, the app goes straight to the requested view - skipping any loading-page you might have made for your app. Again, remember to load whatever resources you need from Isolated Storage.

Then the app fires the view's constructor, before OnNavigatedTo and Loaded goes off.